# Selecting multiple images using xam.plugin.media

Tags: xamarin.forms

I'm using `xam.plugin.media` to get the file path of the image selected. Working with a single image is fine, but I'm having trouble selecting multiple images.

This is my code:

```
List<MediaFile> mediaFile;
...
private async void AddAttachments(object sender, EventArgs e) {
            await CrossMedia.Current.Initialize();
            if (!CrossMedia.Current.IsPickPhotoSupported) {
                await DisplayAlert("Error", "Your phone does not support photo uploads. Please proceed without attachments.", "Okay");
                return;
            }

            mediaFile = await CrossMedia.Current.PickPhotosAsync();

            if (mediaFile == null) {
                return;
            }

        }
```

Despite using PickPhotosAsync(), it still selects a single photo. I was expecting something where I can check images I want to upload like other mobile applications.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you can't (kind of). It is supposed to be working, but there was an issue about this back in 2018-2019, which got marked as solved, even though the user kept complaining about it not working reliably/always.
Link to the feature request/issue [here](https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/MediaPlugin/issues/153).

There is a new issue, that got registered recently (April 2020) [here](https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/MediaPlugin/issues/844).

My advice is to subscribe to it and comment, so that the developer will know that you are experiencing some issues with this functionality also. If you can, you can also create a sample project and upload it, so that they can quickly fix it.

However, in my experience, this package hasn't been frequently updated, so you might have to wait a bit.